# error(3061) when trying to export database from Microsoft Access to Excel (2016)

Tags: vba, ms-access

am getting this error

> "Run Time Error 3061=Too Few Parameters.Expected1"

when try to run this code below in vba to export my database from Access to Excel(2016) :-

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SQL As String
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
DoCmd.Hourglass (True)

SQL = "SELECT PartNo, PartName, Price, SalePrice, " & _
"(Price - SalePrice) / Price AS Discount " & _
"FROM Parts " & _
"ORDER BY PartNo "

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set xlApp = Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

With xlSheet
       Do While Not rs1.EOF
        .Range("A" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!PartNo, "")
        .Range("B" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!PartName, "")
        .Range("C" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Price, 0)
        .Range("D" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!SalePrice, 0)
        .Range("F" & i).Value = Nz(rs1!Discount, 0)

        i = i + 1
        rs1.MoveNext
     Loop
 End With
SubExit:
On Error Resume Next

DoCmd.Hourglass False
xlApp.Visible = True
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing

Exit Sub

SubError:
MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & "= " & Err.Description,    vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
    "An error occurred"
GoTo SubExit
```

and vba highlighted this line `xlApp.Visible = True` in debug,
i got this code from some tutorial in youtube and they didnt get this error.
so what do u think causing this error ?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely to be with your SQL/recordset. Copy the sql string using a debug.print statement in your code and then paste it into a new query to check that you get the result you're expecting. Also check the field names in your table and recordset.

Comment: exactly,there was a problem with the SQL code, fixed it and now its working after also giving the "i" an initial value,thanks